# I need help web scraping comments section

Tags: web-scraping

I am currently doing a project on football players. I am trying to scrape some public comments on football players for sentiment analysis. However I can't seem to scrape the comment. Any help would be MUCH appreciated. It is the comments part I can't seem to do. Weirdly enough I had it working but then it stopped and I cant seem to get scraping comments again. The website I am scraping from is : https://sofifa.com/player/192985/kevin-de-bruyne/200025/

```
likes = []
dislikes = []
follows = []
comments = []

driver_path = '/Users/niallmcnulty/Desktop/GeneralAssembly/Lessons/DSI11-lessons/week05/day2_web_scraping_and_apis/web_scraping/selenium-examples/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)


# i = 0

for url in tqdm_notebook(urls):

    driver.get(url)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    sleep(0.2)

    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')

    try:
        dislike = soup1.find('button', attrs = {'class':'bp3-button bp3-minimal bp3-intent-danger dislike-btn need-sign-in'}).find('span',{'class':'count'}).text.strip()         
        dislikes.append(dislike)
    except:
        pass

    try:
        like = soup1.find('button', attrs = {'class':'bp3-button bp3-minimal bp3-intent-success like-btn need-sign-in'}).find('span',{'class':'count'}).text.strip()
        likes.append(like)
    except:
        pass

    try:
        follow = soup1.find('button', attrs = {'class':'bp3-button bp3-minimal follow-btn need-sign-in'}).find('span',{'class':'count'}).text.strip()
        follows.append(follow)
    except:
        pass

    try:
        comment = soup1.find_all('p').text[0:10]
        comments.append(comment)
    except:
        pass

#     i += 1

#     if i % 5 == 0:
#         sentiment = pd.DataFrame({"dislikes":dislikes,"likes":likes,"follows":follows,"comments":comments})
#         sentiment.to_csv('/Users/niallmcnulty/Desktop/GeneralAssembly/Lessons/DSI11-lessons/projects/cap-csv/sentiment.csv')

sentiment_final = pd.DataFrame({"dislikes":dislikes,"likes":likes,"follows":follows,"comments":comments})
# df_sent = pd.merge(df, sentiment, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: comments seem to be included by a script, and not be part of the main page...

Answer (score 0):

The comments section is dynamically loaded. you can try to capture it using the driver,

```
try:
    comment_elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')
    for comment in comment_elements:
        comments.append(comment.text)
except:
    pass
print(Comments)
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. It works but occasionally it stops with the error that errays aren't the same length. This can be 4 iterations through or sometimes 10 etc.

Comment: Are you referring to the error from pandas dataframe?

Comment: ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Comment: # figure out the index, if necessary